# asp.net listbox first item from mysql DataReader not visible

Tags: mysql, asp.net, listbox

I have several list boxes and even a checkbox list that are populated from a SELECT statement that queries a MySql DB.  Each of the lists populates correctly and with the correct data, however, the first item in each list box doesn't show up.  For example i have a box with 7 items (0-6) and each are there but only 1-6 show up on the web page for the user to select.  I have my code below but I can't for the life of me figure out why it's doing this.

```
Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand("SELECT id, name FROM assets WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT assetid FROM assetsout WHERE qty = @qty AND " & _
                                     "(@undate BETWEEN undate AND avdate)) AND checkout = @chk ORDER BY name", cn)
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@chk", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "true"
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@qty", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "0"

        Dim undate As Date = txtNeeded.Text

        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@undate", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = undate

        Dim dr2 As MySqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
        dr2.Read()
        ListBox1.DataSource = dr2
        ListBox1.DataTextField = "name"
        ListBox1.DataValueField = "id"
        ListBox1.DataBind()
        cmd.Dispose()
        dr2.Dispose()
        cmd2.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `dr2.Read()`, you are reading past the first row. It is no longer available when you call `DataBind()`.

Comment: so what would a better option be?  Use a dataadapter and fill it like a datagrid instead?

Comment: just don't call the read method before you call databind. Also, off topic but important, you should call dispose on your reader and connection in a finally block.

Comment: Yep that fixed it, once again thanks for helping me with an idiot error ;)